# Binding data in Hub Control in Windows universal apps with list items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

Hello I have list defined as follows

```
public class Article
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}
public static List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
```

I use a async method to get xml data from server and parse it.

```
private async void Button_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //Progress Bar
        prg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        string xml = string.Empty;            
        Uri url = new Uri("http://someurl.com/someting.php");
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Parsing to start");
            string eve = "article";
            XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            foreach (var item in loadedData.Descendants(eve))
            {

                try
                {
                    Article c = new Article();
                    c.title = item.Element("title").Value;
                    c.author = item.Element("author").Value;
                    c.content = item.Element("content").Value;
                    articles.Add(c);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Failed");
                }

            }

            Debug.WriteLine("About to add items");
            articlelist.DataContext = articles;
            Debug.WriteLine("Items added");
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Parsing Failed");
        }
        prg.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

}
```

Below is the xaml UI elments

```
<Page
   x:Class="Airtrixz.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:Airtrixz"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" x:Name="prg" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Airtrixz" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30"/>

       <Hub Margin="0,50" Foreground="White">
           <HubSection Header="posts" x:Name="articlelist" >
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding title}" Height="25" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding author}" Height="25"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding content}" Height="25"/>
                </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>

            </HubSection>
        </Hub>

       <Button Width="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="50" Tapped="Button_Tapped" Content="Load"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Doing `articlelist.DataContext=articles` seems to be fine. But no list items are being displayed and it gives the following error for title, content and author properties in HubSection

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'title' property not found on 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Airtrixz.MainPage+Article, Airtirxz.WindowsPhone, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. BindingExpression: Path='title' DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Airtrixz.MainPage+Article, Airtirxz.WindowsPhone, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Could anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: By looking only at the error message it seems like the context of your `TextBoxes` is the list of `Articles` and not the individual object. Don't you need some sort of `ItemsControl` to loop through your collection to populate `HubSections`?

Comment: @Jerrington I'm a beginner over here, would you mind elaborating on how I can populate    HubSections using   ItemsControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your HubSection's DataTemplate is a StackPanel, it will only display a single object, not an entire list of articles. For that you need a ListBox or a ListView. This is why you are getting the Bindings error; it is trying to find the 'title' property on your List, which of course is not there. Try this:

```
<Hub Margin="0,50" Foreground="White">
    <HubSection Header="posts" x:Name="articlelist" >
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding title}" Height="25" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding author}" Height="25"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding content}" Height="25"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

This will bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to the `DataContext` of the `HubSection`, which you are setting to `articles` in your `Button_Tapped` callback, so it should all work. post a reply either way, and I can try to help debug more.

Comment: It did work, no errors now. But the output in each list view item is App2.MainPage+Aritcle. [link]http://imgur.com/7vHJnBE use this link for better view of the problem.

Comment: Glad to help :) XAML and Binding can be pretty confusing when you're first starting out with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should put it here as an answer as I've never used `Hub` control but my guess would be that `HubSections` will have to be populate like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <HubSection Header="posts">
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding title}" Height="25" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding author}" Height="25"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding content}" Height="25"/>
             </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
         </HubSection>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Error: The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "HubSection".

Error: A value of type 'ItemsControl' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList`1'.

It gives the above errors.